# Wi-fi solution for a rooming house

Tags: wireless-networking

I manage a rooming house where we are having a 4 camera system w/ DVR installed soon. The owner has given me the project of getting the system online while providing wifi access to the residents. 
I have contacted the local ISP to get a new cable line run to the house and a modem. What I am looking for is an inexpensive router / AP that can meet these needs:

- Be able to hard-wire the DVR with a static IP address
- Provide wifi access to 6 people spread over 2 stories
- Access controls that require residents to sign into an account or be on a Authorized users list to access the internet
- (Optional) QOS controls to keep distribution of bandwidth equitable between residents.

I'd be grateful for any advice on affordable solutions.
Thanks!

Comment: I guess your question is more suitable in the Hardware Recommendations > http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. To get the public static IP to your router you will need to use port forward ( 'Virtual servers' on some models ) the ports for the DVR, in most cases 80 for WEB viewing and few others, let's say for example 4000 TCP. That is an easy to do job and is pretty straight forward and all modern routers do have that functionality.
2. To provide WIFI to 2 store building is not so trivial of a task. It depends on building construction and room locations, you may not be able to cover both floors and all rooms with good enough signal. Signal quality differs a bit from router to router, but most are capped at TX power up to 500mW. You may need to change the OEM antenna with another high gain omni directional ( most likely 3 of those ). It would be better to use dual band ( 2.4 Ghz + 5 Ghz ) router for the job so at least the clients capable of using the 802.11ac can benefit from the longer range. Third party firmwares like DD-WRT may provide option for TX power increase on some models. There are smartphone apps that can help you fine tune the signal coverage after install and apps to plan the location beforehand, so you may want to 'survey' the building beforehand for best install location and probable coverage with different models before actual install.
3. The way i get Access Control is something like Remote Authentication Dial In User Service - Radius auth. ( Correct me if i don't understand the question ). You have the WEP/WPA layer of protection with all routers, that is a password to access the wireless network. The security of that implementation is questionable at best, WEP is totally unusable in terms of security and WPA2 PSK can be attacked as well even by not very technically advanced users using live distros like Kali Linux; Parrot OS; Samurai etc. Not to go in detail, but WPA2 PSK can be compromised in matter of minutes by capturing the handshake of connecting user ( you can force deauth/ disconnect the user so he must reconnect and that way you can capture the handshake ), then a wordlist is used to 'crack' the password, that's why you do not use default SSID because SSID is used as salt for the password and rainbow tables can be used to speed the 'crack' on default SSID names. The way to have every user auth with his own username and password is to implement WPA2 Enterprise /  IEEE 802.1X. In brief it is mostly done via Radius server, free alternatives do exist - FreeRadius. This is something that must be covered in depth and i'm barely touching the surface and being as simple in the description as i could be, so if you decide to go that route post a question and i will guide you thru the process.
4. QOS is integrated in most modern routers in the firmware, implementation differs between models and manufacturers, but it mostly get the job done, in such small environment it won't be a problem. If you're talking about limiting /shape/ the speed per user that is another thing and done in deiferent way, but also is possible in some router models via stock firmware.

If you need to really go cheap and effective than the solution is [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) / [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/)/ [Gargoyle](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/) etc.. some third party firmware that covers all of the above functionality. Go to their router database and select an affordable router to re-flash with the third party firmware.